# Rust/WebAssembly VS pure JavaScript benchmark in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, webassembly

I've wanted to try Rust and WebAssembly for a while. I recently realized that I could try both at the same time by compiling Rust to WebAssembly.

I wanted to know what the performances of something like that would be so I came up with a simple test :

1. Make a few mathematical operations in pure js a few times in a loop and measure execution time
2. Do the same thing in a Rust function, compiled to WebAssembly and imported into Node.js
3. Compare results

**Does this approach make any sense to you?**

**Does my implementation below make any sense to you?**

**Am I benchmarking what I think I am benchmarking?**

---

`index.js`

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const fs = require('fs');
var source = fs.readFileSync('./compute.wasm');

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  const start = process.hrtime.bigint();

  let n = 1000000;

  let js_result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    js_result += Math.sqrt(i) / Math.exp(i);
  }

  const js = process.hrtime.bigint();

  const env = {
    memoryBase: 0,
    tableBase: 0,
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
      initial: 256
    }),
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({
      initial: 0,
      element: 'anyfunc'
    })
  }

  var typedArray = new Uint8Array(source);

  WebAssembly.instantiate(typedArray, {
    env: env
  }).then(result => {
    const wasm_result = result.instance.exports.compute(n);
    const wasm = process.hrtime.bigint();
    const js_time = js - start;
    const wasm_time = wasm - js;
    const winner = js_time > wasm_time ? "wasm" : "js";
    const str = `+==========+================================+================================+
|          | time (ns)                      | result                         |
+----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| js       | ${js_time}${" ".repeat(31 - js_time.toString().length)}| ${js_result}${" ".repeat(31 - js_result.toString().length)}|
+----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| wasm     | ${wasm_time}${" ".repeat(31 - wasm_time.toString().length)}| ${wasm_result}${" ".repeat(31 - wasm_result.toString().length)}|
+==========+================================+================================+
${winner} wins!`;
    res.end(str);

  }).catch(e => {
    // error caught
    console.log(e);
    res.end("err");
  });


});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

`compute.rs`

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn compute(idx: i32) -> f64 {
    let mut sum = 0.0;
    for i in 0..idx {
        sum += (i as f64).sqrt() / (i as f64).exp();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Compile this code as follows

```
rustup update
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
rustc --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -O --crate-type=cdylib compute.rs -o compute.big.wasm
```

Reduce the size by removing unused stuff from the module:

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc 
wasm-gc compute.big.wasm compute.wasm
```

Run the app `node index.js` and go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` to output the result, for example

```
+==========+================================+================================+
|          | time (ns)                      | result                         |
+----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| js       | 35706500                       | 0.7072407184868039             |
+----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| wasm     | 6141100                        | 0.7072407184868039             |
+==========+================================+================================+
wasm wins!
```

Comment: I'm not sure this benchmark makes much sense. First of all you're measuring something "precompiled" and already optimized (Rust, the loop...) vs something that will be possibly compiled the first time it will be needed (yes, also wasm code has to be compiled to machine code but it's so simple than even a fast single pass streaming AoT compiler can do a great job). So yes, in general wasm is MUCH more efficient than JS. How much? It depends on what you're doing. You may even cherry-pick some code where a good JS engine can run the same code at nearly native speed but that won't prove anything.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes, comparing the two is the point. Although compiled rust should be faster, I've read that some browsers might actually execute wasm slower than native js, which is why I'm trying it myself :) As far as benchmarking goes, I'm aware that a cherry-picked piece of code does not prove anything. What I'm asking here is some code review from people like you who are experienced with rust/wasm/js integration and are able to tell me if I'm doing something wrong in my little experimentation :)